# Error: 10548. Invalid Configuration. The merchant's account is not able to process transactions

Tags: api, paypal

I am trying to invoke the PayPal API in my source code for processing credit-card transaction. It looks to be working perfect on Sandbox, but throwing an error like below on Live in response.

```
Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2018-03-14T17:42:19Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 8d47b259e776b
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 3.2
    [BUILD] => 39949200
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10548
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Invalid Configuration
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => This transaction cannot be processed. The merchant's account is not able to process transactions.
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
    [AMT] => 26.55
    [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
)
```

The parameters being sent in request object appears to be like below.

```
Array
(
    [USER] => <my_username>
    [PWD] => <my_password>
    [SIGNATURE] => <signature>
    [METHOD] => DoDirectPayment
    [PAYMENTACTION] => Sale
    [IPADDRESS] => <my_server_ip_address>
    [VERSION] => 3.2
    [AMT] => 26.55
    [CREDITCARDTYPE] => Visa
    [ACCT] => <credit_card_number>
    [STARTDATE] =>
    [EXPDATE] => 032023
    [CVV2] => 111
    [FIRSTNAME] => <acct_first_name>
    [LASTNAME] => <acct_last_name>
    [STREET] =>
    [CITY] =>
    [STATE] =>
    [COUNTRYCODE] =>
    [ZIP] =>
    [EMAIL] => <acct_email_id_at_domain.com>
    [PHONENUM] =>
    [CURRENCYCODE] =>
    [BUTTONSOURCE] => osCommerce22_Default_DP
)
```

I am done with checking it a "Business Account" along with presence of "Home Phone Number" and "Customer Service Phone Number" in the profile, and found everything working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to process a direct card payment using the API operation DoDirectPayment. In order to process a direct card payment, you will need to have PayPal Business account with PRO. But your Live PayPal account doesn't have PRO, this is the reason for getting an error code 10548.Here you are using Classic API for processing the payment. Please contact PayPal MTS team at https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/ for the suitable latest product in order to process a direct card payment.